# ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite Creates Multiple VBAProjects for workbook in VBA Window

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, vbe

My workbook has the following open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
End Sub
```

And then this button:

```
Sub UnlockDeveloper()
Dim pwd As String

pwd = InputBox("Enter developer password:", "Password")

If pwd = "password" Then
    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite
    End If
Else
    MsgBox ("Incorrect password.")
End If

End Sub
```

This all works fine, usually, but sometimes running the UnlockDeveloper sub causes the VBAProject to appear twice in the VBA window, and I have no way of knowing which is the real file. If I make changes in the wrong one the changes are lost as soon as I close Excel.

[image: screenshot]

Anyone got any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: Very interesting question, I recalled having seen something similar on Dicks Blog some years back, found [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/11/google-desktop/) which makes it clear there a variety of causes for the problem, and workarounds that have worked in some cases.

Comment: As for why this happens, there is an [explanation on the msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193344%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I could not find a direct solution but I think the [build-in functionality of read-only mode](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/read-only-workbook.html) can be useful?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/728-tips-adding-a-password-to-make-an-excel-workbook-read-only) make your coding obsolete?

Comment: I have tried under Excel 2016 for Windows and Excel 2011 for mac. I am unable to re-produce this issue. It appears to work as intended: opens as read only when first loaded, and once correct password is typed on a button, it makes it read and write enabled. When I go into VBA Developer, there is only one project there. I noticed that Excel closes the existing one, and opens it again when correct password is entered in read write mode.

Answer (score 1):

The VBE will sometimes keep "Ghost Projects" in the VBE, even if the host document has closed. In this instance, the `ChangeFileAccess` method is closing the workbook (and leaving a Ghost Project for it), and then opening a new instance of the workbook with a *real* Project, but as you observe, it's hard to differentiate between the Ghost and the real project.

So, the *underlying* problem is the persistence of Ghost projects.

[Ghost projects](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/980) are typically caused by an add-in maintaining a reference to a project. The host application (Excel) closes the host document, and asks the VBE to remove the project, but the VBE sees that something still has a reference to the project, and so does not unload the project.

In my experience, it is usually a COM addin that is incorrectly holding a reference to the project(s). You can identify the culprit by disabling COM add-ins one-by-one, until the problem is no longer reproducible. Then re-enable the add-ins that don't cause the problem. You may need to check the add-ins for Excel *and* for the VBE.

On my PC, the culprit has always been the Power Query Add-in, and disabling the add-in (and restarting Excel) has always fixed the problem, but YMMV.